# How to display null records/rows from table

Tags: oracle, table, null

For ex: I have a record with `name` = "sga_target", and no record exists where `name` = "_exafusion_enabled". I still want to display a row with "_exafusion_enabled" as `name` and NULL as `value`, without using an outer join with any other table.

```
select name,value from v$spparameter where name 
in('_exafusion_enabled','sga_target');
```

Desired output :

```
name                 value
-------------------- -----
sga_target           18G
_exafusion_enabled   null
```

(actually `name` column does not have the value "_exafusion_enabled")

How can we do this?

Comment: In other words, how do you select from a table something that is not there? You can't. And what's wrong with outer join?

Comment: @mustaccio - the `MODEL` clause let's you add rows to a resulting data set.  So, yes, it is possible, but (imho) not maintainable.

Comment: To clarify - do you want to hard-code in "_exafusion_enabled" with a NULL value, assuming that you'll never have a row with that name? Or is this a case where you want a row with a NULL value if the `name` doesn't exist, and the row with the actual value if it does?

Comment: What's wrong with using an outer join?

Answer (score 1):

I'd go about trying to feed the input in using a "pseudo-table" or view .. (as opposed to an IN clause):

here's a very simple example ... if you have more requirements on how to feed the values in, there's lots of examples around the web showing how to build a "table" like w_input, with the data coming in.

```
  with w_input as (
        select 'sga_target'  name from dual union all
        select '_exafusion_enabled'  from dual
     )
  select wi.name, nvl(sp.value,'null') value
    from w_input  wi
        LEFT OUTER JOIN v$spparameter  sp
           ON sp.name = wi.name
  /


  NAME               VALUE
  ------------------ ------------------------------
  sga_target         1610612736
  _exafusion_enabled null

  2 rows selected.
```

Comment: Even though the OP specified they didn't want a `OUTER JOIN` solution, they might not have understood this possibility. It's worth proposing (and is the best solution I can think of).

Comment: yeah, not sure why that restriction, to be honest ... (and also honest: I didn't notice it until you pointed it out ... heh)   *shrug*

Comment: Maybe they just meant that there was no second table involved *in their query* that would provide a natural way to get the NULL in `value`; or, maybe there's a dictate from above not to use an `OUTER JOIN`. The OP can always note that this violates their requirements, if they can't use it - it's still the best answer I can think of.

Comment: I just made a minute change and it served my purpose.Great thought Ditto!!!
World is full of innovators and creative people...Kudos...

Answer (score -1):

```
select name,value 
from v$spparameter 
where name = 'sga_target'
Union all
Select '_exafusion_enabled', Null 
from dual
```

Comment: I assume that, if there *is* a row where `name` = "_exafusion_enabled", the OP wants to see that row, and *not* have an extra row with that name and a NULL value.

Comment: @RDFozz  I don't assume, that's not what he said...

Comment: @RDFozz The op specifically states that there is no record for the second row that is desired in the results.

Comment: @JoeW - OK, you're right; there is nothing that explicitly states that, in the future, "_exafusion_enabled" will be added, and that the OP would want to use the actual value in that case instead of NULL. I have merely assumed that's true. I'll ask.